# Start headless X server as non-root user

Tags: x11, non-root-user

Trying to start headless X server (driver "Dummy" from package xorg-x11-drv-dummy) as non-root user from ssh session on Centos 7 machine with command like

`$ nohup Xorg -noreset +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER -logfile /my/log/file -config /my/config/file :9 >> /my/log/x.out 2>&1 &`

...and everything works OK except that non-root condition - in such case I find in log file

`(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
        Perhaps you do not have console ownership?
(EE)`

... this headless X server is used just to run selenium tests and no "console" is actually needed (no need for window manager either)

do you have any clue what is wrong with such configuration?

adding currently used config file :

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
  Driver      "dummy"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
  HorizSync 31.5-48.5
  VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier  "Default Screen"
  Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
  Device      "Configured Video Device"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1024x800"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: What part of the command makes it headless?

Comment: @AlexStragies have you seen the config file (I am asking because such a question may help, not because I want speculation, from some one that knows the same as me).

Comment: added missing config file - plus I expected that just specifying "driver dummy" to do the headless trick - but maybe I'm mistaken

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `Xvfb` (virtual framebuffer X server) for your headless setup? This one doesn't try to use a virtual console, which seems to be the problem.

Comment: thought that Xvfb is deprecated by this dummy driver since 2016